# How does ClickOnce ensure publishing is atomic

Tags: .net, clickonce

When I publish an update to a ClickOnce application, the client application will not try to download the update until the new version is completely deployed.

Do you know of a reference to where this process is explained?

Is it simply that it updates the manifest file last, only after the new version is completely copied over?

I ask because I am looking into replicating the deployment directory structure so that customers in our satellite offices can access a local copy of the deployment.  I want to ensure the replication process we choose does not create a race condition with the ClickOnce client update functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an update to a ClickOnce application, it copies over all of the files, and then when it has verified they are all "in place", it copies the deployment manifest (.application file). This is because the deployment manifest in the top folder of the deployment location determines the version of the application that is installed/updated as well as the location of the files download (from Application Files/versionedfolder).

As for the satellite offices, be aware that the installation URL is where ClickOnce will look for any updates, so even if you copy the files to somewhere, it will still look in the original location for them. Are the satellite offices just too far from the main location? Do they have a shared file server you can put the files on? If so, you could just change the installation URL for them and put a copy of the deployment on a local file share.